# How can I use scroll to modify CSS transform scale?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to scale a div using the scroll function.

I can get it to modify the width causing images to get larger but not the scale inside the transform function which is what i need for my design.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).scroll(function() {

      var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
      $('.layer1').css({
          what goes here to modify transform: scale() ?
        }


      })
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="layer1">
  <div class="image1">
    <img src="resources/images/bg/01.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="image2">
    <img src="resources/images/bg/02.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="image3">
    <img src="resources/images/bg/03.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

I want the div "layer1" to scale dependent on the scroll function but i can't tie it to the scale function alone.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Would you please update your question with a better description of what you hope will happen? For example, should the element grow/shrink in relation to how far down the page you've scrolled? Does it just animate after a specific number of pixels?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
let scroll = $(window).scrollTop() / 30 /* Is the ratio */;
button.css("transform", "scale("+ scroll +", "+ scroll +")");
```

You need to add a ratio because the scale 2 is like double the size and the scroll position is too big.

Comment: this actually works great! i see what you mean about it reacting too fast, i'll play around with it to get it where it looks right. Thanks!